# How to use includes on a single column in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looping through companies and collecting all of the employee names for each company:

```
companies = Company.all
companies.each do |company|
  employee_names = company.employees.pluck(:name)
  # do work, I still need access to the company object
end
```

That will do a separate query to get the employee names for each company. The Bullet gem suggested to add `includes(:employees)`. So I attempted:

```
companies = Company.includes(:employees)
companies.each do |company|
  employee_names = company.employees.collect(&:name)
  # do work
end
```

This successfully minimizes the amount of queries, but the request actually takes longer! I'm assuming that is because the `includes` loads the entire set of `employees` into memory, but I only need the name.

**Is there a better way to do an includes but only on a specific column (or columns)?**

Comment: Try removing `.all` at the end of the query

Comment: Sorry, the code above is an example. I'm unable to post the actual source code on here. That was a typo from the pseudo code.

Comment: You should see the generated queries and their execution times in the log files (`log/development.log` by default). Could you post them here?

Comment: Try doing `Company.includes(:employees).pluck(employees: {:name})` or `Company.joins(:employees).pluck(employees: {:name})` and see any improvement in the response time.

Comment: @Pavlan, I think you meant `[:name]` instead of `{:name}`, right?

Comment: @GregNavis Nope. I meant `{:name}`

Comment: @Pavlan `pluck(employees: {:name})` doesn't work for me, but `pluck('employees.name')` does. Using this did solve the issue for me, thanks!

Comment: @Pavlan: `{:name}` isn't valid Ruby syntax. You've solved the issue though so further discussion seems to be pointless. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way is DB specific. For `PostgreSQL`:

```
SELECT_CLAUSE = <<~SQL
  companies.*,
  array(
    SELECT name FROM employees WHERE company_id = companies.id
  ) as employee_names
SQL
# ...
companies = Company.select(SELECT_CLAUSE)
companies.each do |company|
  # company.employee_names # => Array
end
```

Or don't instantiate model instances at all:

```
PLUCK_COLUMN = 'array(SELECT name FROM employees WHERE company_id = companies.id)'
# ...
companies = Company.pluck( :id, :title, PLUCK_COLUMN )
# [
#   [ 1, 'Apple', [ 'John', 'Vasya', ... ] ],
#   ...
```

Don't forget about indexes and pagination if you have a lot of data.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `Company` indexed on `employee_id`. It seems to me that the issue is that you're now doing work in the query that you used to do in the application memory. If you want to query company information based on certain employees, which seems to be the case, you will want to have the Company table to have an index on `employee_id`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any built-in Rails solution for this special use case.

However, you might be able to solve it by emulating *sort of* what `includes` does, with the difference that you call `pluck` in the end:

```
companies = Company.all.to_a
#=> [#<Company:...>, #<Company:...>, ...]

company_ids = companies.map(&:id)
#=> [1, 2, 3, 5, ...]

company_employee_map = Employee.
  where(company_id: company_ids).
  pluck(:company_id, :name).
  inject({}) { |hash, (company_id, name)|
    hash[company_id] ||= []
    hash[company_id] << name
    hash
  }

companies.each do |company|
  employee_names = company_employee_map[company.id]
end
```

The code is untested, so it might need some adjustments.